# Why decorator on instance properties is executed before decorator on static properties?

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I am new to TypeScript. I am curious why decorators on instance properties are executed before decorators on static properties?

Is there any reason behind this?

Considering the code below:

```
function LogProp(target: any, propertyName: string | Symbol) {
  console.log(`Prop Decorator: ${propertyName} is logged`);
}

function LogMethod(
  target: any,
  name: string | Symbol,
  descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
) {
  console.log(`Method Decorator: ${name} is logged`);
}

class Book {
  @LogProp
  static staticProp: string;
  @LogProp
  instanceProp: string;

  constructor(val: string) {
    this.instanceProp = val;
  }

  @LogMethod
  instanceMethod() {
    return this.instanceProp;
  }

  @LogMethod
  static staticMethod() {
    return Math.random();
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAGTgcwAoCc4AcAUUAhlmgKZQBciRYAngDSK465lZR0ByRAtmdQDOULDDBpEAH0QBlOrwBGcADYBKRAG8AUIkQQEglWQB0y9PgAG2PIgAiZfViJQ4WagBINLPO049+AL6IMIKIZmjkACYWqgDcWgFaWqCQsAgo6ACyFAAWcJH4OojEpBTUtIxFYHwCiMKi4lKy8krKDEWRZIIQorgubojWbBx09t29-Vrq2rr6YIbKJuGW2VB5kXYOrs6uHhrVgcGh4VEx8YlaEMpEgqEAQnBwANaaRQACqJisRcLOMBB1YiwCBDIQiMRoeK6D7oIZFMS-SBkUGAhqQpKzAwiEDQVz4ABuRGUYLR0yKujWIWMCOISKGiAAvIhCcooYgLtDPqt1vD5rSIGRufl8GTdLosBQQFgkJTBNS+bQBUM2RzEDC0ELIj8gf9AX8IJqRa8xYgJVApUhMs4csYnGBInBeCKVQkgA)

The output is:

```
Prop Decorator: instanceProp is logged
Method Decorator: instanceMethod is logged
Prop Decorator: staticProp is logged
Method Decorator: staticMethod is logged
```

Why?

Comment: I can tell you the behavior is [documented](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-evaluation), but it doesn't say *why*.

Comment: It makes more sense when you realize that the decoration is happening during creation of the *prototype* the class will apply to instances, not instances themselves (your code doesn't even create an instance). There's [a note](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators) in the property decorators section talking about that, saying that no property descriptor is provided because instance properties don't exist on prototypes (which is true). But I'm not immediately finding their reason for doing the prototype first (though in some way it makes sense to me).